# How to merge MergedDictionaries, inside app.xaml, with an URI from a DictionaryResource as a content file locate on a Library project,

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on the localization feature of our wpf project. We need to have the language files accessible and not compiled.
Based on this project tutorial : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamic-localization-in-wpf/
I have made some changes on the project. First, I have add a new library project, and move the language dictionnary to this new project.

```
Original MainWindow.xaml:

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="i18N/MainWindow.en-US.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

The new library project is called Localization. And the folder i18N with files have been moved on this new project.
I have removed the line related to the dictionary on the MainWindow.xaml. It is working even if there is warning : with ResourceKey could not be resolved.

Where I'm stuck is that I can't reference the URI of a default language in the MainWindow.xaml file. Knowing that this Content resource is in the Localization library and not in the main project.

```
I have tried those lines
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/i18N/MainWindow.en-US.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/../i18N/MainWindow.en-US.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/../i18N/MainWindow.en-US.xaml"/>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion ?
Thank you

Comment: Content is not located in some library at runtime. It should be copied to the output directory of the executable app.

Comment: @mm8 the linguage files are copied to the output directory of the executable file. On each file like MainWindow.en-EN.xaml, the propertie Copyto Output Directory is set to : Copy if newer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Localization;component/i18N/MainWindow.en-US.xaml"/>
```

> The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that is located in a subfolder of the referenced assembly's project folder.
> pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml

This quote comes from this link that details many different scenarios. Maybe you will find the solution among these proposals.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Yes, I've already tried it. It works in the designer but an exception occurs at runtime. The xaml file is not a compiled resource that is part of the assembly. The language file is marked as content, and it is copied to the output directory at compile time.